# Cannot change Windows Python Installation Path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've once installed `Python 3.6.2 - 32bit`, however I wanted to install the `64` bit Version. When I want to uninstall it with the Windows Installer it tells me `No Python 3.6 installation was detected`. When I know choose `Modify` It only gives me a grayed out path.

[image]

Any Solutions how to get rid of it and reinstall?

Comment: You could try to find the files that it installed with python and delete them

Answer (score 0):

I went a very old school way, I've used the old `RegScanner` Tool to search for any occurrences of `Python36`. Deleted all **Keys/Values**, restarted the machine and was able to uninstall it when launching the Python Installer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem as this and ended up needing to:

1. Check "Add or remove programs" for previous versions of Python.
2. Download the installer for that version.
3. Repair the older version of Python Windows thought was installed.
4. Uninstall the older version.
5. Try to install the newer version again.

Answer (score 0):

I could not too
i found the solution :
first i uninstall all ( i like the free Iobit uninstaller because clean all leftovers , but that is optional )
After install again  a new installation and choose ;
Install for all users in this computer , after "next" step
you will  be able to choose what directory you want

i hope can help

Answer (score -1):

1. Have you tried to uninstalling it , from control panel first remove
   the installed package
2. Make sure you installing as administrator
3. Still not helped then try uninstaller tool(here is one : http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Uninstallers/Advanced-Uninstaller.shtml)

Comment: I rather don't want to install a third party software to remove something from my computer, there must be an easier way? I was already trying to remove it from the `apps and features`

Comment: Are you running as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I've even deleted all the registry edit's that have `python36` in it, still no luck.

Comment: alternately you can install anaconda 64 bit that comes with external python libraries